# Parse XML using Nokogiri in Rails to compare a database table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a table called "users", which has three columns:

```
id, ref, name
```

I want to parse the following XML document using Nokogiri and list the matched and unmatched records by comparing the values in the "users" table records:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EXPORT>
  <DETAIL>
    <ID>150</ID>
    <REF>188440</REF>
    <USER>Bruce</USER>
  </DETAIL>
    <DETAIL>
    <ID>1501003</ID>
    <REF>1884402</REF>
    <USER>Alice</USER>
  </DETAIL>
</EXPORT>
```

For example:

```
Users.where(id: 1501003).name
Users.where(ref: 188440).name
```

Find the `name` by comparing the `id` and `ref`.

Note: if `id` does not match, then compare with `ref`. If `id` matches then ignore `ref`.

I tried:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(self.filename))
exp = "//EXPORT/DETAIL"

NODES = doc.xpath(exp)

nodes.each do |node|
  unless node.text.nil?
    User.where(id: node.text).first.name
end
```

Comment: Please explain *why* you want to use Nokogiri to do lookups from what appears to be a database dump in XML. That seems terribly awkward and a very slow and fragile solution. If the data is in a database search against it. If it's not and you want to find records to load then load the data into a separate table and select the desired records from it and insert into the master. A DB XML dump can easily exceed available RAM making your plan unviable. Using a SAX parser might help but still, there's smell to the solution. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder why you want to use Nokogiri to do lookups from what appears to be a database dump in XML. That seems terribly awkward and a very slow and fragile solution.

A database XML dump can easily exceed available RAM making your plan unviable. Using a SAX parser might help but still, there's smell to the solution. See "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)".

- If the data is already in a database, search against it and select the records you need.
- If it's not and you want to find records to load, then load the data into a separate table and select the desired records from it and insert them into the master.

Comment: Thank you very much Tin Man